# Covariance of censored/clipped Gaussians

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, gaussian

I am interested in the covariance of two clipped (or censored) Gaussian variables.

More precisely, let $g_1 \sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$ and $g_2 \sim N(0,\sigma_2^2)$ be two (dependent) Gaussians with $\operatorname{Cov}(g_1, g_2) = \operatorname{E}(g_1 \cdot g_2) = \alpha$. For $\tau \geq 0$, does there exist a closed expression (or a good estimate) for
$$
\operatorname{E}(\operatorname{clip}(g_1, \tau) \cdot \operatorname{clip}(g_2, \tau)),
$$
where $\operatorname{clip}(x,\tau) := \operatorname{sign}(x) \cdot \min\{|x|, \tau\}$?

I am grateful for any hint!

I already asked this on MathStackExchange, but unfortunately got no answer yet: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025538/covariance-of-censored-clipped-gaussians

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this has to be done numerically. However, note that if you specify that the random variables are Gaussian, and specify their means and variances and covariance, that does not completely determine their joint distribution. But it does if they are _jointly_ Gaussian, i.e. the pair is so distributed that every constant linear combination of them is Gaussian. $\qquad$

Comment: I played around with this in Mathematica and don't see any hope of a closed form expression.

Comment: I think you are right. But thanks for trying! Probably, I will next try to find tight bounds that mimic the asymptotic behavior of this expression with respect to $\tau$.